# Angular *ngIf expression with number and string concatenation

Tags: angular, validation, indexing, expression

I have a div with `*ngIf="agreement.errors?.required"` and I also have an index defined as `i`.

I want to add the value of the index  or `i` to the word agreement before evaluating the overall value of `"agreement<i>.errors?.required"`.

Comment: Is the variable agreement an array?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't shove agreements into an array?

Comment: agreement1, agreement2, agreement3 etc. are all formcontrols (that all will have their own validators), and I was trying to avoid an array if possible.

Comment: You can try *ngIf="agreement{{i}}.~~~~"

Comment: @chulphan, thanks, I had tried that but get some non-sense like this `Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined`

Comment: I should add that when I do use an array of strings `"agreement1.errors?.required"` and implement to `*ngIf="agreement[i]"` works perfect, so not sure how to implement the way I want to.

Comment: Can you show more of the template? Please show the `agreement` control together with the `*ngIf` condition, so that we can see how the two are related. If an `*ngFor` loop is used, please include it also.

Comment: You are asking us to guess whats on your mind and what your work looks like based on a poor explanation of your problem and provided us with nothing worth noting, dude we're not magicians, can you give us more information, show us the relevant parts of your code with an example if you like but closely related to the source.

Comment: Instead of "building" a variable name with a number, you should use an array. That would be used like `*ngIf="agreement[i + 1].errors?.required"`. "The way you want to" is usually **not** a good idea. (smelling like a x/y problem)

Answer (score 0):

noone really refers to fields of a class in that way in angular, but if you really need it you can make it in this way:

```
*ngIf="this['agreement' + i].errors?.required"
```

but the better option would be to use an array instead.

Comment: thanks that makes sense and works, but thinking through the array approach, I created a question I have with it though, would you mind looking at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060072/angular-put-form-field-validation-rule-ex-firstname-dirty-into-typescript