# Angular - Put form field validation rule ( ex. firstname.dirty ) into TypeScript array?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, validation

How can I store form field validation rules into an array? What would I replace  /'''''HERE'''''/  with?

```
formfields:  Array<Object> = [
    {label: "Employer:", control: "employer", validations: "{requirederror: "employer.errors?.required && employer.dirty", notvaliderror: "employer.errors?.maxlength && employer.dirty"}"},
    {label: "Phone:",    control: "phone",    validations: "{requirederror: "phone.errors?.required && phone.dirty", notvaliderror: "phone.errors?.pattern && phone.dirty"},
    {label: "Email:",    control: "email",    validations: "{requirederror: "email.errors?.required && email.dirty", notvaliderror: "email.errors?.email && email.dirty"}"}
];

<div *ngFor="let formfield of formfields; let i = index">
     <div class="labelandinput">
          <label class="label">{{formfield.label}}</label>
          <input class="input" formControlName="{{formfield.control}}">
          <div class="formfielderror" *ngIf=" /'''''HERE'''''/ ">...</div>
          <div class="formfielderror" *ngIf=" /'''''HERE'''''/ ">...</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Is it as simple as doing this?

```
  <div class="formfielderror" *ngIf="{{formfield.validations.requirederror}}"> SOME REQUIRED ERROR </div>
  <div class="formfielderror" *ngIf="{{formfield.validations.notvaliderror}}"> SOME NOT VALID ERROR </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should rethink how you refer to your data. Usually array represents a set of similar items, and every item could be a javascript object, describing one item.

Let's assume you are using reactive forms. i.e. your array can look somehow like

```
myItems = [
 formBulder.group({
   firstname: ['',[Validators.required(), Validators.pattern(/[0-9]+/)]],
   hobby: [''] // no validators here
 })
]
```

Then you can render it with this markup

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myItems" [formGroup]="item">
  <input type="text" formControlName="firstName">
 <div *ngIf="item.firstName.errors?.required">firstname is required. please fill it</div>
 <div *ngIf="item.firstName.errors?.pattern">firstname should follow [0-9]+ pattern</div>
  
  <input type="text" formControlName="hobby">
</div>
```

Hope this example is enough to get you started.

If you need only one form for one item then no array is required. Just `form = formBuilder.group({...})` would be enough, and no iterating with *ngFor in the template would be required

Comment: I was debating on how much code to actually show here, but I added it in.

Comment: ohhh, that is not going to work. I don't even know what to fix here, because everything is not right. you should really try to follow angular form guides and try to make forms in a guides proposed way, and then, probably invent a new way of using forms, if you don't like the gides method